# SDL2: how to raise window (on top of calling terminal)

Tags: c++, centos6, sdl-2

The window always pops up in the background, but I want it to be in the foreground, at least in front of the terminal, in which the code is executed that opens the window.

I do not need focus on that window, so just raising without focus would be ok.
([SDL2 Raising a window without giving it focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126617/sdl2-raising-a-window-without-giving-it-focus)).

I've tried all SDL_WindowFlags, but none seems to help.
Also SDL_RaiseWindow() did not help.

The window is meant for graphically displaying results of a terminal program.
I compiled SDL2 from source 2.0.3 on CentOs 6.4

I compile the below program and start it from a bash terminal in KDE (Focus stealing prevention level: low, Focus Policy: click to focus).

Example code:

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int, char**){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!", 100, 100, 640, 480,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_INPUT_GRABBED |
        SDL_WINDOW_INPUT_FOCUS | SDL_WINDOW_MOUSE_FOCUS |
        SDL_WINDOW_FOREIGN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    SDL_RaiseWindow(win);

    SDL_Delay(4000);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** I've tried the same example in Cygwin64 under windows. The window pops-up in front of the terminal in that case. So is this a CentOS/window-manager problem?

Comment: How are you executing the program? Is the *focus policy* of the *window manager* set to *click to focus*?

Comment: Hi Elvisjames, I compile the above program and start it from a bash terminal in KDE. Focus stealing prevention level: low, Focus Policy: click to focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior in KDE/CentOs depends on the *focus stealing prevention level* setting of the window manager. It was set to *low*.
The window will raise on top when I set it to *none* instead.
My new question is: Can I somehow force the window to be raised, even with setting *low*? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785519/force-window-to-be-raised-with-focus-stealing-prevention-level-low)

The window also raises under Cygwin64 in Windows.